# Does MongoDB Views needs a minimun version? Views not working in 3.2.7

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create some views in a mongodb server using version 3.2.7. The view is created without problems, but when I query the view it doens't show any results.

[image]

The exact same commands works well in my local 4.4.3 mongodb.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo `views` were released on version 3.4. Take a look to the [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4/), in particular [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4/#views) part.

Comment: That's it. I was looking for the release version in the Views page but it doesn't appear there. Thanks so much!